# How to use HTTP POST method in objective C to add an event to a data base

Tags: objective-c, post

I am very new to programming and have started to teach my self how to program in objective C using Xcode. I have look all around about how to add data to a data base using a web service and cannot figure it out. My friend is working with me and has set up code to make the web service link to the database properly using a web page but I cannot figure out how to get these results on my app. I understand that you have to use a POST method and have tried many variations but none of them have work. I am not getting an error and it says that the connection is good but nothing appears to be added when I call it.

Here is the POST method that I am using.

```
    -(void)postMethod
{
   [self.connection cancel];

    //initialize new mutable data
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    self.receivedData = data;

    //initialize url that is going to be fetched.
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.hockeynearby.com/webservices/gameevent"];

    //initialize a request from url
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url standardizedURL]];

    //set http method
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    //initialize a post data
    NSString *post = @"player=A5EC4F9CB48B8F635A9BE06AFB979CEB&match=8C2A918F71C2908CCE3AF9C86FB3A1CA&series=05BA1FA3B4ACC585F9103ECDCA678F4B&team=87CDC95F7200E5DCC175F125216A493B&event=G&type=ES&period=3&minute=12&second=45&value=1&comments=test&id=8C2A918F71C2908CCE3AF9C86FB3A1CA";
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    //Here you can give your parameters value

    //set request content type we MUST set this value.

    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    //set post data of request


    //initialize a connection from request
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    self.connection = connection;


    //start the connection
    [connection start];
```

I apologize if it is difficult to follow, as I said I am very new to this and have a limited understanding.

Here is the web service code

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"       `xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://gameevent.cxf.example.camel.apache.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" name="GameEventService"   targetNamespace="http://gameevent.cxf.example.camel.apache.org/">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://gameevent.cxf.example.camel.apache.org/" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://gameevent.cxf.example.camel.apache.org/">
<xs:complexType name="gameEventPojo">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="comments" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="event" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="match" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="minute" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="period" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="player" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="second" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="series" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="team" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="type" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="value" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="outputReportIncident">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="code" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="id" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="inputStatusIncident">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="incidentId" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="outputStatusIncident">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="status" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="reportGameEvent" type="reportGameEvent"/>
<xs:complexType name="reportGameEvent">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="gameEventPojo"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="reportGameEventResponse" type="reportGameEventResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="reportGameEventResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="outputReportIncident"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="statusGameEvent" type="statusGameEvent"/>
<xs:complexType name="statusGameEvent">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="inputStatusIncident"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="statusGameEventResponse" type="statusGameEventResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="statusGameEventResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="outputStatusIncident"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="statusGameEventResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:statusGameEventResponse" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="reportGameEventResponse">
<wsdl:part element="tns:reportGameEventResponse" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="reportGameEvent">
<wsdl:part element="tns:reportGameEvent" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="statusGameEvent">
<wsdl:part element="tns:statusGameEvent" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="GameEventServicePortType">
<wsdl:operation name="reportGameEvent">
<wsdl:input message="tns:reportGameEvent" name="reportGameEvent"></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:reportGameEventResponse" name="reportGameEventResponse"></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="statusGameEvent">
<wsdl:input message="tns:statusGameEvent" name="statusGameEvent"></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="tns:statusGameEventResponse" name="statusGameEventResponse"></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="GameEventServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:GameEventServicePortType">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="reportGameEvent">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="reportGameEvent">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="reportGameEventResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
<wsdl:operation name="statusGameEvent">
<soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input name="statusGameEvent">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="statusGameEventResponse">
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="GameEventService">
<wsdl:port binding="tns:GameEventServiceSoapBinding" name="GameEventServicePort">
<soap:address location="http://hockeynearby.com/webservices/gameevent/reportGameEvent"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Thank you so much for help in advance. 
I apologize because I have virtually no understanding of the web service. This was all set up by a friend. If you need any other information please ask and I will try to put it up quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library. It helps to simplify you work with web server

Here is POST Example

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

[AFNetworking tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial)

Comment: Would this be added to my code or instead of my code? Also is AFNetworking in Xcode already or do I have to download it and set it up?

Comment: this is instead of your code. follow the link which i have added there is HOWTO about adding AFNetworking to your project. Basicaly you just need to drag&drop AFNetworking folder to your Xcode project and then import it
I have updated my answer to tutorial links

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll do this then accept your answer!